# Problem with Sympy lambdify with functions of 'x' or constants

Tags: python, sympy, constant-expression, lambdify

I have working code using sympy.lambdify for a user input function string and then to plot the function. It fails if the function entered is just a constant number.

The code I am using is

```
import sympy as sy
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = sy.symbols('x')
func = 5
x_range = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
F = sy.lambdify(x, func, "numpy")
y_range = F(x_range)
plt.plot(x_range, y_range)
```

So if func is a valid function like "2*x" or "sin(x) - 7*x**2", the code works fine.

However, if I enter a constant, say "5", I get a single number in y_range, not an array like x_range with all elements equal to the value of the entered constant. Therefore, I get a value error

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (200,) and (1,)
```

I have played with this for so long, I am beginning to feel like it is an error or inconsistency in sympy.

Does any one have a suggestion please?

Comment: Please show what `func` is when you get the error. If it just does `return 5`, why do you expect that `5` to magically turn into an array? To clarify, the `x` part of `"2x"` and `"sin (x)..."` is what makes it an array if `x` is an array

Comment: Yes Pranav, I get that, but what if I want my function to be "0x + 5", which is what I want. (I have tried this, but it still does not work)

Comment: @KitingPaul I must say disagree. I would expect the result of lambdify for a constant to be a *fuction* that returns this constant.

Comment: Yes, sadly that is true, I think it is inconsistent but I have tested for a constant and allowed for this option and it is working now. Thanks for everyone's help :)

Comment: `help(F)` should show the python code.  `lambdify` doesn't do a deep analysis; it's basically a lexical translator.

Comment: When you try to lambdify something like `expr = 0*x+5`, did you first look at `expr`?  `sympy` has reduced that to `5`, so `lambdify` isn't getting anything different.  I run `sympy` in an interactive session, not as a standalone script.  I need to check intermediate values, results line by line.  You could have avoided the plot error if you had looked at `yrange`.